# Ubuntu slave in Jenkins using ec2 plugin

Tags: windows, ubuntu, jenkins

Could you please mention clear steps to add Ubuntu/Windows slave in Jenkins using ec2 plugin?

I tried adding Ubuntu slave in Jenkins using an ec2-plugin, finding the error below:

````
Dec 03, 2019 9:22:34 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Exception trying to authenticate Exception: java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed.
Dec 03, 2019 9:22:34 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Authentication failed. Trying again...
Dec 03, 2019 9:23:04 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Authenticating as ubuntu 
Dec 03, 2019 9:23:04 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to 172.31.4.2 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Dec 03, 2019 9:23:04 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Dec 03, 2019 9:23:04 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Exception trying to authenticate Exception: java.io.IOException: Publickey authentication failed.
Dec 03, 2019 9:23:04 AM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
WARNING: Authentication failed. Trying again...```
````

Comment: Please provide additional information. Which guide are you currently trying to get working? How does your setup look like? Which authentication method is used? In general, anything that could help us get familiar with your setup and your problem.

Comment: With the help of this document I am trying add ubuntu slave dynamically in jenkins   https://www.kisphp.com/linux/tutorials/setup-jenkins-server-on-aws-ec2-with-slave-agents
I am able to add redhat linux slave , the same way I am trying for ubuntu and windows